# SSL setup error (ERROR 2026 (HY000):failed to set ciphers to use)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ssl, opensuse

### Background

I am having a strange problem without any solution for the last 24 hours. I have just set up SSL following the guides available in the internet. My sever runs Suse linux. After ssl setup my `mysql` configuration file `/etc/my.cnf` looks like the following.

**Client config:**

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/client-key.pem
```

**MySQL server config:**

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
# Change following line if you want to store your database elsewhere
datadir = /MySQL
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
default_storage_engine = myisam
ssl
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

**SSL Status:**

When I log in to `mysql` it shows SSL up and running.

```
mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                      |
+---------------+----------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                        |
| have_ssl      | YES                        |
| ssl_ca        | /etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath    |                            |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                            |
| ssl_key       | /etc/mysql/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+----------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another check to see the status for SSL.

```
mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.33, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Connection id:          5
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Current pager:          less
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.33 openSUSE package
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 2 min 2 sec

Threads: 4  Questions: 280  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 40  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 33  Queries per second avg: 2.295
--------------
```

Now I have created a user named `TestuserSSL` that requires SSL to connect to the mysql server and has access to only one database named `TraccarDEV`. Checked the user previlage using the following.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'TestuserSSL'@'%';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for TestuserSSL@%                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'TestuserSSL'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6C47D9CD3A183D230B04FE7F38D7D313E2B4B5AE' REQUIRE X509 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `TraccarDEV`.* TO 'TestuserSSL'@'%'                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Problem:

Now from console when I try to log in to `mysql` as user `TestuserSSL` using

```
mysql --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem -u TestuserSSL -p
```

the console asks for password and after entering password I keep on getting the irritating error!

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: Failed to set ciphers to use
```

After goggling for hours I could not find any solution to this issue. Hope the experts here can show me the right path.

BR

Comment: did you find a solution to this?